# Laravel Vuejs , How to prevent user to go to some route and still make the method work

Tags: laravel, routes, axios, vuejs3

So I'm using Laravel 8 and Vuejs 3,

I have Route::get in my web.php that call method that are in my controller which fecth data from database and ont the Vue side, I have an axios get request that get the url to retrieve the data.

```
Route::get('/trainee',[UserController::class,'getTrainees']);
Route::get('/instructor',[UserController::class,'getInstructors']);
Route::get('/acpCenter',[AcpCenterController::class,'getAcpCenter']);
```

Thos are some of my routes in my Web.php, but I don't want to user to reach those page and I want them to be redirected to the login page.

I try to use middleware, but when I do, I can't retrieve my data with axios.

```
   /**
     * This method allow us to retrieve all the trainee that have been created to allow
     * the user of the application to search specific trainees
     */
    getTrainee() {
        axios.get(AXIOS + 'trainee')
            .then(response => this.trainees = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },

    getInstructor() {
        axios.get(AXIOS + 'instructor')
            .then(response => this.instructors = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },

   getAcpCenters() {
        axios.get(AXIOS + 'acpCenter')
            .then(response => this.acpCenters = response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    },
```

This is how I call my method on the Vue side.
So I still want to acces the data but I don't want to reach the page where the data is displayed.

Any idea on how I can do it ?

Comment: Will you mind providing 1. AXIOS variable value 2. Error message while making axios call 3. Middleware and user data which can prove that it satisfies middleware

Comment: @GangadharDarsi I think that's a mistake from me to want to prevent the acces of those url, because If they are not accessible, Axios won't be able to get them, and they aren't showing safety data so I don't know if they must be prevent

Comment: make sure logged-in user has right permissions to access the routes . You can go through spatie packages to learn more about roles and permissions in laravel